# Using fullcalendar with javascript, how to modify a parameters list and refetch?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar to show events to be filled.

In my team, I have 2 people. Mike and Claire. I'm the Boss.

If Mike or Claire log in to my page they can only see their own Events.
If I log to the same app I can choose the events to see: Mike's, Claire's, all of them or only mine.

To do that I'll choose the correct value from a Combobox (Mike's, Claire's, Mine, All of them). After I change that combovalue I have to refetch events according to my selected option.

Actually my fullcalendar is configured with:

```
events: "../controller.php",
dparams : {
    "pg":"getAgendaCalendarView",
    "profile": "undefined",
    "query": "*"
},
```

And under my combo I have something like:

```
listeners: {
'change' : function(objThis, newValue, oldValue){
    $('#cw_tbcalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
}
```

My main question is, how can I modify the parameters list to show my selected value?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [ExtJS's calender](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/calendar/index.html)? (tagged with extjs)

In reply to the question, might this be your solution?

```
var config = {
    events: "controller.php",
    dparams: {
        "pg": "getAgendaCalendarView",
        "profile": "undefined",
        "query": "*"
    }
};
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(config);

$('#my_combo').change(function() {
    config.dparams.query = $(this).value();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar(config);
});
```